# How can I delete several pages of text from my Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

I have a Google Docs file that contains about 250 pages of text. Only pages 180-230 apply to me, so I wanted to delete the unnecessary pages from the document.

I have tried to drag my cursor over the text, but of course, this is very unpractical as there are hundreds of pages I would have to drag my cursor over.

So, is there any way for me to select the text on select pages in the document and then delete it?

Answer (score 1):

Use Google Docs keyboard shortcuts. First, put the insertion cursor before the first page that you want to keep, then select every thing from that position to the beginning of the document, then press the delete key.

| Shortcut for PC |  |
| --- | --- |
| Extend selection to the beginning of the document | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> |

Resource

[Keyboard shortcuts for Google Docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/179738?hl=en)